Which Passport.js strategy should I use in my project: passport-local, passport-localapikey, or some OAuth?
I'm currently learning web development using Typescript and Express. The project I'm working on is a journal-like application in which users can keep journals. Naturally, users must have an account to use it. I'd implement my own code for authentication, but I was told not to do that and use existing libraries instead.
I researched a bit and found Passport, which seems to be what I'm looking for. It asks to choose a strategy, however. And I don't know which of these ones to choose:

passport-local;
passport-localapikey;
passport-google-oauth, or another OAuth one.

For what I understood, using the third option would make the authentication data be stored out of my application server, and the user would have to log in with Google, GitHub, Auth0, for example. Is that correct? I would like to have an option for logging in with just email and password too, so should I choose one of the other strategies?
If I should choose a local strategy, which should I choose? It seems passport-local is just what I wanted. My application is a RESTful API, though, so should I use passport-localapikey intead?
